# how to use regex to search for a float pattern inside a list

Tags: python, regex

So I have the following list of data:

```
lst_text = ['---', 'Project-Desc: kytos/kytos-end-to-end-tester', 'Last-Status: failed', 'pytest summary:  12 failed, 49 passed in 2919.10 seconds ']
```

I need to extract the "2919.10 seconds" from there.

I have this code :

```
summary = re.findall(r"\d+ \w+", lst_text[3])
```

So far, the regex that extracts the summary does not account for decimal points and also expects a space between a number and word. That current line of code just returns "10".

However, I need to recheck the regex expression, so that it also includes floating point numbers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? \w+` but `\w` also matches a digit. Do you only want `2919.10 seconds` and can the `\w+` contain digits?

Comment: from another conversation, the following pattern: "\b\d+\.\d+\s*\w+" also works for my intended use case which is to match "2919.19 seconds" and "45.13s" and extract the float numbers.

Comment: Or `\b\d+\.\d+\s*[^\W_\d]+` if there should be word characters following except digits or an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the floating point value followed by the word after from the fourth item in the list:

```
\b\d+\.\d+\s+\w+
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `\d+\.\d+` Match 1+ digits, a `.` and 1+ digits
- `\s+\w+` Match 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars

Updated example code

```
import re
lst_text = ['---', 'Project-Desc: kytos/kytos-end-to-end-tester', 'Last-Status: failed', 'pytest summary:  12 failed, 49 passed in 2919.10 seconds ']
summary = re.findall(r"\b\d+\.\d+\s+\w+", lst_text[3])
print(summary)
```

**Note** that `\w` can also match a digit, so `2919.10 12345` would for example also match.

Output

```
['2919.10 seconds']
```